# Java Object Scope

Tags: java, object, scope

I am trying to create an object based on a condition, therefore the object creation is within the conditional's scope, however I need to see the object outside of that scope. I thought adding it to a Map would work, but it doesn't. Consider the following example:

**TestModel.java**

```
public class TestModel {
private String text;
public void setText(String text){
this.text = text;}
public String getText(){
return this.text;}
}
```

**ScopeTest.java**

```
import java.util.*;
class ScopeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestModel testModel;
Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

for (int i=1; i<2; i++){ // if a certain condition is met, create an object as below
    testModel = new TestModel();
    testModel.setText("test text");
    myModel.put("test", testModel);
    }

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : myModel.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("key=" + key); // I can see the key value
    System.out.println("value.getText()=" + value.getText()); // but can't see testModel object. I am not sure how to resolve.
}
}
}
```

cheers,

Geofrey Rainey.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "can't see myModel object"?

Comment: What do you mean "cannot see"? Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: hm.. I got it ... you are trying to call getText() method on an instance of Object class... Either you should create Map<String, TestModel> in the first place or cast the entry.getValue() as TestModel and change the type of value to TestModel..

Comment: do you know that you can access your `testModel` object directly with out putting it into a map ?? so you don't need the cast operation at all !!

Comment: Yes an error is thrown for this example as: "cannot find symbol".

However the real version of this code is actually written in springmvc 3 and the value of the object is null when printed to a logfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the Object value with your Class.  Like this.

```
System.out.println("value.getText()=" + ((TestModel) value).getText());
```

If you dont want to cast the object then you can use like this.

```
class ScopeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestModel testModel;
Map<String, TestModel> myModel = new HashMap<String, TestModel>();//Use TestModel
                                                                instead of object

for (int i=1; i<2; i++){ 
    testModel = new TestModel();
    testModel.setText("test text");
    myModel.put("test", testModel);
    }

for (Entry<String, TestModel> entry : myModel.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    TestModel value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("key=" + key); 
    System.out.println("value.getText()=" + value.getText()); 
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. It seems you're all correct after I tried it. I will retest in the springmvc code to see if that works too, hopefully it's all good. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the Object into your model.

```
TestModel value = (TestModel) entry.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to cast the object returned by the HashMap to be a TestModel before you can use a method of that class.

Comment: Right that does make sense, however I am sure I was doing that but let me clarify. This is an example of what is actually written in the springmvc framework.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `TestModel` as generic type of value in your Map like below?

```
Map<String, TestModel> myModel = new HashMap<>();
//          ^^^^^^^^^ - instead of Object
```

This way you can iterate over your map with

```
for (Map.Entry<String, TestModel> entry : myModel.entrySet()) {
    ...
}
```

and you will be able to store value in

```
TestModel value = entry.getValue();
```

without needing to cast it. Now since type of `value` reference will be `TestModel` compiler will let you use its methods like `getText()` without problems.

```
System.out.println("value.getText()=" + value.getText());
```

---

Also I am not sure why you are using loop if you want to iterate over it once. Simple `if` would be better. Another thing is using `Map` to hold one element seems unnecessary. You can just use one reference like

```
boolean someCondition = true;

TestModel testModel = null;
if (someCondition) { // if a certain condition is met, create
    testModel = new TestModel();
    testModel.setText("test text");
}

if (testModel!=null){
    System.out.println(testModel.getText());
}
```